# Getting Data from web server in background in objective-C

Tags: iphone, web-services, background, objective-c-blocks

I want to create one iPhone application which will pull Data from web server after every specific time interval. even if the applilcation is running in background.

I have try to get data after every perticuler time interval. but when application goes in background. The NStimer can not fier the event. and I can not give call to web service.

I have also the to call web service using **Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)** using the following code

```
NSTimeInterval delay_in_seconds = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay_in_seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_after(delay, queue, ^{
    // perform your background tasks here. It's a block, so variables available in the calling method can be referenced here.


    // now dispatch a new block on the main thread, to update our UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self setBackgoundProcess];

    });
});
```

But still I am unable to fetch the data. It is not working when application goes in background.

Is there any whey to make call for web service in background in iPhone

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), the  *Background Execution and Multitasking* section. Basically, you can either specify that your app needs to run in background (it will run until the iOS kills it on low memory) or you can specify that you need to execute a finite task when the app enters in background (guess the first case fits your needs more)